# Can you write a trigger in SQL that activates when two tables change?

Tags: sql, database

I was writing a trigger, and I was wondering if I could you do something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_1
AFTER DELETE ON Table1 AND INSERT ON Table2
```

I know you can't do it exactly like that, but maybe someone more experienced has already thought of a way to do something similar to this. Thanks!

Comment: And what code would these two events share???

Comment: Why have you tagged this with two different RDBMSs? Which are you using? I've removed the tags. Please retag with only the appropriate one.

Comment: Why not write 2 separate triggers? Also, is this Oracle RDBMS?